# Woocommerce update product price via AJAX

Tags: ajax, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to update price of a product added to CART.

I can easily change quantity in the CART, but price doesn't work at all.

```
function total_count($cart_object){
$total_cart = intval($_POST['total_cart']);
$product_id = $_POST['order_id'];
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key=>$value ) {

    //Single product
    if ( $value['product_id'] == $product_id ) {
        $value['data']->set_price($total_cart);
    }
}
//to check if is work or not
wp_send_json(array($value['data']->get_price($total_cart)));
}
```

After my AJAX call is succesfull I got wp_send_json with the price I want to, but cart never updates.

AJAX call

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'total_count', total_cart: number, order_id: order_id },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(order_id);
        jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
        //jQuery('body').html( data );
    }
});
```